# remove items from array with array_filter or array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

I usually use `foreach` loop to remove some items from array.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$item){
    if($item == 'something'){
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Is this possible to remove items via `array_walk` or `array_filter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$newarray = array_filter($array, function($var) {
    return ($var != 'something');
});
```

Comment: With the advent of PHP 5.6.0, it's also possible to filter by key with `$newarray = array_filter($array, function($key) { return preg_match('/something/', $key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);` or `function($value, $key)` with the ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH flag if the condition is looking at both key and value.